# Drupal Drush master-branch in Windows 10 home requires composer - What and why?

Tags: composer-php, windows-10, drush, drupal-8

After I installed Drush (master-branch for Drupal 8) at my Windows 10 home and set PATH EV with all it's needed values, I ran `drush cc all`... And then I got that error:

> C:\wamp\www\benia>drush cc all Failed loading c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.4.0rc1-7.0-vc14-x86_64.dll
>
> Unable to load autoload.php.
>
> Drush now requires Composer in order to install its dependencies and autoload classes. Please see README.md.

I am not yet a programmer, and have no idea why would Drush need the Composer software, and how to install it on Windows 10 home for using Drush. Can someone please write a detailed, stepped answer, for laymen like me, how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the Windows installer for Composer should take care of everything you need. You can find it [here](https://getcomposer.org/download/). If you prefer to use the command line the Composer site also has instructions for that.

Examples, Using cUrl:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Using PHP:

```
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php
```

Comment: Hey man, I've installed it from the installer in a default course (I.E without "Shell menus"). After I finished the installation I went to cmd, and typed cd/ cd wamp/www/benia, and after navigating typed drush cc all, but the original error about composer installation seems to persist. Should I uninstall and then reinstall with "Shell menus" ? Or maybe there is just some kind of an action between the installation I performed and Drush, that I haven't performed yet?

Comment: Make sure that the directory you installed it to is actually in the PATH variable. Then make sure the `composer.bat` and `composer.phar` are in the install location. If not follow the [manual install](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#manual-installation) steps.